# Dynamically show required textfield depending on dropdownlist value

Tags: dynamic, yii, textfield, show-hide

Good day. My problem is I have a dropDownlist with three options: A, B, C. What I need to do is to show a textfield depending on what the user chose.

Example: user chose A => it will show textfield AA (which should be required and not empty)
         user chose B => it will show textfield BB (which should be required and not empty)
         user chose C => it will show textfield CC (which should be required and not empty)

Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

EDIT: It's working now. The only problem now is when an I leave the chosen textfield as blank and it shows the error, the textfield that was shown (the one which is dependent on the value of dropdownlist) disappears or goes back to state display:hidden. This happens right after the 'textfield cannot be blank' error message. The initial chosen value of dropdownList is still there and is still on focus but the textfield disappears.

HERE ARE MY UPDATED CODES:

VIEW:

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'org_type'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'org_type', $model::getOrgType(), array('prompt'=>'', 'id'=>'orgType')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'org_type'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row" style="display:none" id="sec">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sec_ref'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'sec_ref', array('id'=>'secField')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'sec_ref'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row" style="display:none" id="dti">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dti_ref'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'dti_ref', array('id'=>'dtiField')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'dti_ref'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row" style="display:none" id="cda">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cda_ref'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'cda_ref', array('id'=>'cdaField')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'cda_ref'); ?>
</div>
```

MODEL:

```
    public function addCustomError($attribute, $error) {
    $this->customErrors[] = array($attribute, $error);
}

/**
 */
protected function beforeValidate() {
    $r = parent::beforeValidate();

    if ($this->org_type == 'Single') {//this is the checkbox

        $this->validatorList->add(CValidator::createValidator('required',$this,'dti_ref',array()));

    }

    if ($this->org_type == 'Partnership') {//this is the checkbox

        $this->validatorList->add(CValidator::createValidator('required',$this,'sec_ref',array()));

    }

    if ($this->org_type == 'Corporation') {//this is the checkbox

        $this->validatorList->add(CValidator::createValidator('required',$this,'sec_ref',array()));

    }

    if ($this->org_type == 'Cooperative') {//this is the checkbox

        $this->validatorList->add(CValidator::createValidator('required',$this,'cda_ref',array()));

    }
    foreach ($this->customErrors as $param) {
        $this->addError($param[0], $param[1]);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Javascript on View:

```
<script>
"$('#orgType').change(function(){
if($('#orgType').val() == 'Single')
{
    $('#dti').show();
    $('#dtiField').addClass('required');
    $('#cda').hide();
    $('#sec').hide();

}
if(($('#orgType').val() == 'Partnership') || ($('#orgType').val() == 'Corporation'))
{
    $('#sec').show();
    $('#secField').addClass('required');
    $('#dti').hide();
    $('#cda').hide();
}
if($('#orgType').val() == 'Cooperative')
{
    $('#cda').show();
    $('#cdaField').addClass('required');
    $('#dti').hide();
    $('#sec').hide();
}
return false;
})";
```

Comment: What did you try actually ?

Comment: I can already show/hide dive depending on the dropdownlist value but I do not know how to make the showing div a required element.

Comment: Please add your model rules and view code

Comment: okay. but How do I put the code it. I'm pasting here on the comment box but it says too many characters. I'm sorry I'm new here. Please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Oh okay. wait. I'll upload it. thanks.

Comment: Get dropdown selected value using JavaScript and dynamically change textfield **ID** and **fieldname**. No need to use three different textfields. After this you can apply validation in models.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

After Every change event of DropDown You can set value to the text Filed ..

Comment: I already did that. I only have one problem left. Can you please check  my updated codes and see if you can help me? Thanks.